# Loaded UIView from NIB - Wrong Frame Size

Tags: ios

Ok, so I've created a `UIView` in interface builder. I'm using `AutoLayout` and I've got one subview of this view pinned to all four sides.

Here's what I don't understand. When I load this NIB file using `loadNibNamed`. I then get a reference to the view. I set the frame for this view. And yet, when I access the subview (using [`containerView viewWithTag:1`]) it's frame hasn't been automatically resized. What gives? If you change the frame for a parent view, why wouldn't the subview frame change as well?

It doesn't make any sense.

Why can't you just load a `UIView`, set it's frame and have all the subviews adjust as appropriate (ESPECIALLY since I'm using `AutoLayout`!)?

EDIT: To be clear, all I want to do is be able to define a `UIView` hierarchy in IB with appropriate `AutoLayout` constraints and then be able to load and display that view on the screen sometimes at different sizes? Why is this so hard?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UIKit doesn't update subview geometry immediately when you change a view's geometry.  It batches up the updates for efficiency.

After running your event handler, UIKit checks whether any views in the on-screen window hierarchy need to be laid out.  If it finds any, it lays them out by solving your layout constraints (if you have any) and then sending `layoutSubviews`.

If you want to solve the constraints and lay out a view's subviews immediately, simply send `layoutIfNeeded` to the view:

```
someView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);
[someView layoutIfNeeded];
// The frames of someView.subviews are now up-to-date.
```

Comment: Rob, you are a gentleman and a scholar. THANK YOU! Can you explain something for me though - when I created my NIB really all I defined in there was a set of relationships between items. Absolutely no hardcoded sizes. The only one subview is just pinned to the walls of the parent view (ie. a relationship between the parent and the child where the parent says "whatever size I become, you become"). So...really, when you first load the NIB in code, it shouldn't have a view size anyway and the first setting of the frame should create the proper size? Why doesn't it work this way?

Comment: When you load the nib, the views have whatever sizes were defined for them in the nib.  When you change the root view's size in code, you have to run layout for that change to be propagated to children via the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem, I was creating a tutorial view where in which I wanted to add multiple UIViews to a scrollview. While I was trying to get the frame from xib, it gave always 320 and because of that the offset for the pages were wrong and my views looked crappy in iPhone6 and 6plus.

I then used pure autolayout approach, ie instead of using the frame, I added constraints through VFL so that subviews fit exactly to the superview. Below is the snapshot of code where I create around 20 UIViews from Xib and add properly to scrollview

Full code here [ScrollViewAutolayout](https://github.com/anoop4real/ScrollViewAutolayoutViewsFromArray)

```
 Method to layout the childviews in the scrollview.
 @param nil
 @result layout the child views
 */
-(void)layoutViews
{
    NSMutableString *horizontalString = [NSMutableString string];
    // Keep the start of the horizontal constraint
    [horizontalString appendString:@"H:|"];
    for (int i=0; i<viewsArray.count; i++) {
        // Here I am providing the index of the array as the view name key in the dictionary
        [viewsDict setObject:viewsArray[i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%d",i]];
        // Since we are having only one view vertically, then we need to add the constraint now itself. Since we need to have fullscreen, we are giving height equal to the superview.
        NSString *verticalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[%@(==parent)]|", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%d",i]];
        // add the constraint
        [contentScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalString options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
        // Since we need to horizontally arrange, we construct a string, with all the views in array looped and here also we have fullwidth of superview.
        [horizontalString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@(==parent)]", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%d",i]]];
    }
    // Close the string with the parent
    [horizontalString appendString:@"|"];
    // apply the constraint
    [contentScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:horizontalString options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the accepted answer by Rob didn't work for me. This is what worked:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myXib" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:views[0]];
        self.subviews[0].frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height); //ADDED THIS FOR PROPER SIZE   
    }
    return self;
}
```